# Swift: Simplest way to populate TextFields with Contacts data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I've been trying to populate five empty textfields on a viewcontroller with data from the user's contacts.  *[This](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-contacts-framework/)* seems to be the most comprehensive discussion and example of working with the Contacts Framework, but because it's using two viewcontrollers, I just can't get my head wrapped around what gets done where.  Right now, my code basically consists of:

```
var thisContact = [CNContact]()

@IBAction func actionBtn_AddClientsFromContactsBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()

    contactPickerViewController.delegate = self

    presentViewController(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {

    didFetchContacts([contact])

    //The magic should be happening here, right???

    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}


func didFetchContacts(contacts: [CNContact]) {
    for contact in contacts {
        self.thisContact.append(contact)
    }
}
```

The Contacts list appears, and I'm able to select a contact whereafter the view (Contacts list) pops.  When I do a count of `thisContact` - all 529 contacts are counted.

Please enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong/right, and what I need to do to get those five keys' data and get it displayed in the five TextFields.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, I've been overthinking the problem and the solution. the answer was quite easy:

```
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {

    let myContact = contact
    let myContactFirstName = myContact.givenName
    let myContactLastName = myContact.familyName
    let myContactJobTitle = myContact.jobTitle

    outletTextField_UserClientFirstName.text = myContactFirstName.uppercaseString
    outletTextField_UserClientLastName.text = myContactLastName.uppercaseString
    outletTextField_UserClientJobTitle.text = myContactJobTitle


    // Set the contact's work email address.
    var myContactWorkEmailAddress: String!
    for workEmailAddress in contact.emailAddresses {
        if workEmailAddress.label == CNLabelWork {
            myContactWorkEmailAddress = workEmailAddress.value as! String
            outletTextField_UserClientWorkEmailAddress.text = myContactWorkEmailAddress
            break
        }
    }

    // Set the contact's work phone number.
    var myContactWorkPhoneNumber: String!
    var myContactWorkPhoneNumberArray = [String]()
    for mainPhone in contact.phoneNumbers {
        if mainPhone.label == CNLabelPhoneNumberMain {
            let mainPhoneValue = mainPhone.value as! CNPhoneNumber
            myContactWorkPhoneNumberArray.append(mainPhoneValue.stringValue)
            myContactWorkPhoneNumber = myContactWorkPhoneNumberArray[0]
            outletTextField_UserClientMobilePhoneNumber.text = myContactWorkPhoneNumber
            break
        }
    }

    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

It might not be perfect, but it works perfectly!